# Including Jquery to my jsp Page

Tags: jquery, jsp

Hi, I've read other questions on this topic but have not found solutions.

Basically I have a web project (spring) where I put the file "jquery-1.10.2.js" in the folder "js" that is inside the folder "webapp".

Now at the top of my JSP i put this tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

But when i run the application i get back this error from the js console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/FollowMeWeb/js/jquery-1.10.2.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't know why.
Some help?

Comment: What happens when you open `http://localhost:8080/FollowMeWeb/js/jquery-1.10.2.js` manually?

Comment: @lub get back 404 Error

Comment: make sure file `jquery-1.10.2.js` exists on your root/FollowMeWeb/js/ folder

Comment: you can use online version of jquery `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: @MohitArora Yes i'm sure: jquery-1.10.2.js it's inside the folder "FollowMeWeb\src\main\webapp\js\"

Comment: @Farshad and it's ok... but i still have the proble if i want to add a custom js file.

Comment: @Alist3r you must check your reltive path as I said in my Answer. if you get 404 error when you type absolute address in url of browser [http://localhost:8080/FollowMeWeb/js/jquery-1.10.2.js](http://localhost:8080/FollowMeWeb/js/jquery-1.10.2.js) , therefore your file not exist.

Comment: @Farshad but why if i write "http://localhost:8080/FollowMeWeb/pages/home.jsp" i don't get the error?? The .js folder and the jsp folder are in the same point of my project

Comment: because the file localhost:8080/FollowMeWeb/pages/home.jsp and the `js` located at the same folder

Answer (score 2):

If you have jstl in your page you can simply use this.

```
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/js/jquery-1.10.2.js' />"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's inside the folder "webapp" aswell, I can't see that folder in the GET request.

Make sure you actually add the whole patch to the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure about file `YOURWEBROOTPATH/FollowMeWeb/js/jquery-1.10.2.js` is exist. 
And `js/` folder and `index.jsp` located at the same folder `FollowMeWeb`

or use online library for your webpage :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the file exist as exist "MYWEBROOTPATH/FollowMeWeb/pages/index.jsp"
And ok i can load the file from web but i need to add some custom js files

Comment: oh your current folder is `FollowMeWeb/pages/` must set : `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: also doesn't work with `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: when you include js file script in `MYWEBROOTPATH/FollowMeWeb/pages/index.jsp` , you must set relative address to `../js/jquery-1.10.2.js` and if `MYWEBROOTPATH/FollowMeWeb/home.jsp` relative address is`./js/jquery-1.10.2.js` or `js/jquery-1.10.2.js`

Comment: i've tryed all: `js/jquery-1.10.2.js` or `../js/jquery-1.10.2.js` or `/js/jquery-1.10.2.js` or the complete path. I still have the error

Comment: finaly I recommend to download jquery library online from `http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` and put on js folder and call new jquery located in js folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59996/discussion-between-farshad-and-alist3r).